# Creating permutation of vectors in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to create a combination of graph edges which are stored inside a vector. I need to generate AND store the generated vectors in a vector as well. Below is what I have done so far but it is not compiling at the moment;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

struct edge{

int a;
int b;
int weight;
edge(int u,int v,int cost)
{
    a=u;
    b=v;
    weight=cost;
}

};


int main()
 {
  typedef std::vector<edge> V; //<or_any_class>
  V v;

    v.push_back(1,2,10);
    v.push_back(1,3,10);
    v.push_back(1,4,10);
    v.push_back(3,4,10);
    v.push_back(3,5,10);
    v.push_back(3,5,10);

  do{
        std::cout<<v[0]<<" "<<v[1]<<" "<<v[2]<<" "<<v[3]<<" "<<v[4]<<std::endl;
    }

   while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));
return 0;
 }

What Im trying to get as output;

 1 2
 1 3
 1 4
 3 4
 3 5
 4 3
 1 2 1 3
 1 2 1 4
```

Any hints?

Comment: no match for ‘operator<’ in .....

Comment: @AmaarBokhari: Please give errors in a reasonable amount of detail. Saying "it doesn't compile" is no help to anyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Error one:**

```
 v.push_back(1,2,10);
```

should be

```
 v.push_back(edge(1,2,10));
             ^^^^
```

**Error two:**

You need to define `operator <<` for your `edge` class so that `std::cout<<v[0]` can compile

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const edge& e)
{
     return o << e.a << " " << e.b << " " << e.weight;
}
```

**Error three:**

You need to define `operator <` for your `egde` class so that `std::next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end())` can compile and work

```
bool operator < (const edge& e1, const edge& e2)
{
    if(e1.a != e2.a) return e1.a < e2.a;
    if(e1.b != e2.b) return e1.b < e2.b;
    return e1.weight < e2.weight; 
}
```

Comment: thanks! after correcting it, it stills gives a compilation error.

Comment: @Amaar: Did you see my edit? If yes, what compiler error are you getting?

Comment: @AmaarBokhari: I didn't downvote your question, but seriously you show very little effort to solve your problem yourself

Comment: @AmaarBokhari: I came to the same conclusion as Armen (though I added members to `edge` instead of new non-member functions) and it works for me. Downvotes are likely the result of you giving insufficient detail, especially when it comes to reporting what is actually going wrong!

Comment: @Rook: How on Earth did you manage to have `operator <<` as a member? :)))

Comment: Oh, I got bored of angle brackets and threw in a tostring method instead and called that explicitly from the `cout` line ;-)

Comment: thank you people! i appreciate your help and i'll be careful next time while posting questions. since you already know that I dont have that much hands-on exp with C++, how can i permutate N edges like the one in output?

Comment: @AmaarBokhari: See? Try and you'll gain much more than if someone just gave the solution on a plate

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
v.push_back(1,2,10);
```

should be:

```
v.push_back(edge(1,2,10));
```

Comment: @jrok: Cooler: `v.emplace_back(1,2,10);`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Hm, but I don't think that works for `vector<edge>`.

Comment: My bad, I forgot about constructor. Yes, this is even cooler :)